# How to add multiple conditions to quantstrat?

Tags: r, quantstrat

```
stratMACROSS <- add.indicator(strategy = stratMACROSS, name = "SMA", 
                              arguments = list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=50),
                              label= "ma50" )

stratMACROSS <- add.indicator(strategy = stratMACROSS, name = "SMA", 
                              arguments = list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata)[,1]), n=200),
                              label= "ma200")

stratMACROSS <- add.signal(strategy = stratMACROSS, name="sigCrossover",
                           arguments = list(columns=c("ma50","ma200"), 
                                            relationship="gte"),
                           label="ma50.gt.ma200")

stratMACROSS <- add.signal(strategy = stratMACROSS, name="sigCrossover",    
                           arguments = list(column=c("ma50","ma200"), 
                                            relationship="lt"),
                           label="ma50.lt.ma200")

stratMACROSS <- add.rule(strategy = stratMACROSS, name='ruleSignal', 
                         arguments = list(sigcol="ma50.gt.ma200", sigval=TRUE, 
                                          orderqty=100, ordertype='market', 
                                          orderside='long'),
                         type='enter')

stratMACROSS <- add.rule(strategy = stratMACROSS, name='ruleSignal', 
                         arguments = list(sigcol="ma50.lt.ma200", sigval=TRUE, 
                                          orderqty='all', ordertype='market', 
                                          orderside='long'),
                         type='exit')
```

The above buys stock when moving average(MV) 50 crosses above MV200 and sells when MV50 crosses below MV200. In this code I would like to add two more conditions:

```
Buy
(MV 50 Crosses above MV200) and (close price is above MV50 and MV200)

Sell
(MV 200 Crosses above MV50) and (close price is below MV50 and MV200)
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps look into the signals and see if you can combine them.  So, I would create a signal for when close price is above maV50 & MV200 and label this signal as clgtmv50mv200 and another signal mv50.gt.ma200

```
compt.str <- 'clgtmv50mv200 == 1 & mv50.gt.ma200 == 1'
```

then I would pass that into the formula part of add.signal function with cross=True and label this as your new signal

Comment: Excellent answer to similar question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49827119/quantstrat-how-to-create-multiple-indicators-signal-rules`

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote an enhanced comparison function based on sigComparison. It's not beautiful, also I didn't test the offset functionality.
Tested is the specification of 'and', 'or', 'xor' comparisons, and by using a first and second level comparison it is possible to use up to four columns to retrieve a True / False result column.

```
#'sigCOMP
#'@description signal comparison operators incl and, or, xor for quantstrat signals.
#'@param label name of the output signal
#'@param data the market data
#'@param columns the signal columns to intersect, if a second level comparison is used, the comparison result must reside in the first column only (compare one 2nd level with a True/False Column) or in both, marked by Keyword '2nd'
#'@param relationship operators gte, gt, lte, lt, eq, and, or, xor  TODO:NOT
#'@param secondComparison vector of columns to intersect, if yes, then also set the relationship comparison
#'@param relationshipSecondComparison operators gte, gt, lte, lt, eq
#'@param offset1 optional
#'@param offset2 optional
#'@return a new signal column that intersects the provided columns
#'@export


sigCOMP <- function (label, data = mktdata, columns, relationship = c("gte", "gt", "lte", "lt", "eq", "and", "or", "xor"),  relationshipSecondComparison = c("gte", "gt", "lte", "lt", "eq"), secondComparison, res_not, offset1 = 0, offset2 = 0) 
{
  ret_sig = NULL
  compcols <- NULL

  if(!missing(columns)){
    if (relationship == "op") {
      if (columns[1] %in% c("Close", "Cl", "close")) 
        stop("Close not supported with relationship=='op'")
      switch(columns[1], Low = , low = , bid = {
        relationship = "lt"
      }, Hi = , High = , high = , ask = {
        relationship = "gt"
      })
    } #whatever that is

    colNums <- NULL  
    for(sec in 1:length(columns)){
      if (columns[sec]=='2nd'){
        colNums <- c(colNums,0)
      }
      else{
        colNums <- c(colNums, match.names(columns[sec], colnames(data)))
      }
    }

    opr <- switch(relationship[1], 
                  gt = , `>` = ">",  
                  gte = , gteq = , ge = , `>=` = ">=",
                  lt = , `<` = "<", 
                  lte = , lteq = , le = , `<=` = "<=",
                  eq = , `==` = , `=` = "==",
                  and = "&",
                  or = "|",
                  xor = "xor"
                  # todo: NOT
    )

  } #perform preparation actions if 1|2 columns exist or else stop 
  else {

      stop("only works if two comparison columns are provided. for true/false evaluations you can add e.g. 2nd 2nd or <Signal>, 2nd ")  


  }


  if (!missing(secondComparison))
    {
      ret_sig2nd <- NULL
      opr2nd <- c(1:length(secondComparison))

        if (length(secondComparison) != length(relationshipSecondComparison)){
          stop("make sure to have a comparison operator for each second level comparison you would like to perform")
        } 
        else {

          for (j in 1:length(relationshipSecondComparison)) {
              # run through pairs of columns and relationship checks and return these in a dataframe ret_sig2nd
              # the return column of the appropriate pair will have the name col1 op col2 e.g. close gt nFast

              colNums2nd <- c(0,0)
              comp2ndPartners <- unlist(secondComparison[j])
              relationship2 <- unlist(relationshipSecondComparison)[j]
              colNums2nd[1] <- match.names(comp2ndPartners[1], colnames(data))
              colNums2nd[2] <- match.names(comp2ndPartners[2], colnames(data))
                opr2nd[j] <- switch(relationship2, 
                                  gt = , `>` = ">",  
                                  gte = , gteq = , ge = , `>=` = ">=",
                                  lt = , `<` = "<", 
                                  lte = , lteq = , le = , `<=` = "<=",
                                  eq = , `==` = , `=` = "==",
                                  and = "&",
                                  or = "|",
                                  xor = "xor"
                                  # todo: NOT
              )
               ret_append <- do.call(opr2nd[j], list(data[, colNums2nd[1]] + offset1, 
                                           data[, colNums2nd[2]] + offset2))  

               colnames(ret_append) <- paste0(comp2ndPartners[1]," ",relationship2[j]," ",comp2ndPartners[2])
               ret_sig2nd <- cbind(ret_sig2nd,ret_append)
               rm(ret_append)
            }

          compcols <- ret_sig2nd  
        } # end of 2nd Comp = 2nd Relationship validity block

      if(ncol(compcols)==1){ # check the case if only one second level comparison exists
        transfer2ndToFirst <- compcols  #assumption is, the second level comparison took place with the first column of the first level
        # if one second level comparison is provided, execute transfer object with second column of first level
        compcols <- transfer2ndToFirst[, 1] #offset already included in second level comparison
        compcols <- cbind(compcols, data[, colNums[2]] + offset2)

      } # provide the transfer object to be used in the first level comparison if only one second level comparison exists
    }
    else { # check the case if no second level comparison exists

      # if no second level comparison is provided, only execute first level
      compcols <- data[, colNums[1]] + offset1
      compcols <- cbind(compcols, data[, colNums[2]] + offset2)
    } # if no second level exists, execute comparison for first level only

    # for all cases, perform the first level comparison with the columns stored in compcols - offset has to be applied before storing to compcols 
    ret_sig <- do.call(opr, list(compcols[, 1] , 
                                 compcols[, 2] ))  

  colnames(ret_sig) <- label
  return(ret_sig)
}

# ### TESTS
# # To compare just two (first level) colums
# rm(testOnlyFirst)
# testOnlyFirst<- sigCOMP(
#   columns=c("nSlow","nFast"),
#   relationship=c("gt"),
#   label='GT'
# )
# 
# 
# #To compare a signal or another T/F value with a second level comparison
# rm(testOneSecond)
# testOneSecond<- sigCOMP(
#   columns=c("2nd","exitLong"),
#   relationship=c("and"),
#   secondComparison =list(c("Close", "nFast")),
#   relationshipSecondComparison = list(c("gt")),
#   label='andGT'
# )
# 
# 
# rm(test2Second)
# test2Second<- sigCOMP(
#   columns=c("2nd", "2nd"),
#   relationship=c("or"),
#   secondComparison =list(c("Close", "nFast"), c("Close", "nSlow")),
#   relationshipSecondComparison = list(c("gt"), c("gt")),
#   label='orGT'
# )
# 
# rm(test2SecondOr)
# test2SecondOr<- sigCOMP(
#   columns=c("2nd", "2nd"),
#   relationship=c("or"),
#   secondComparison =list(c("Close", "nFast"), c("Close", "nSlow")),
#   relationshipSecondComparison = list(c("gt"), c("gt")),
#   label='orGT'
# )
# 
# rm(test2SecondXor)
# test2SecondXor<- sigCOMP(
#   columns=c("2nd", "2nd"),
#   relationship=c("xor"),
#   secondComparison =list(c("Close", "nFast"), c("Close", "nSlow")),
#   relationshipSecondComparison = list(c("gt"), c("gt")),
#   label='orGT'
# )
```

Comment: To have the tests working properly, make sure to have an mktdata dataframe in your environment including indicator columns from SMA (i.e. nFast, nSlow) and a signal column 'exitLong' e.g. from RSI, or adapt the testcases to your column names.